# Printing a turtle graphic in a python list

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

I basically want to make it that the list at the bottom calls one of the chosen lists at the top to print whats inside (the size,/location) of the defined turtle drawing.

```
from turtle import *

portrait_01 = ['lines', 2, 1.0, '-']

portrait_02 = ['box_plot', 2, 1.0, '-']


def box_plot():
     for i in range(4):
         forward(50)
         left(90)

def lines():
    pendown()
    forward(50)
    left(90)
    forward(50)
    penup()

portrait_01[0]

pass
```

Comment: You'll have to elaborate a bit more. From your question, it is not clear what you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs a couple of important changes to function correctly.

```
from turtle import *

def box_plot():
    for i in range(4):
        forward(50)
        left(90)

def lines():
    pendown()
    forward(50)
    left(90)
    forward(50)
    penup()

portrait_01 = [lines, 2, 1.0, '-']
portrait_02 = [box_plot, 2, 1.0, '-']

portrait_01[0]()

mainloop()
```

Firstly, you need to put the actual function into the list, not a string. And then you need to *call* the function using `()`. We need to put the list definitions after the function definitions, because the functions need to be defined before you can put them into the lists.

I've also added `mainloop()` to the end of your script to keep the window open until the user closes it.

You could even do

```
portraits = (portrait_01, portrait_02)
portraits[0][0]()
```

`portraits[0]` gets the `portrait_01` list from `portraits`
`portraits[0][0]` gets the `lines` function and
`portraits[0][0]()` calls the `lines` function.

---

Your question doesn't make it clear what the other items in the portrait lists mean, so I can't help you with that. But at least you now know how to call the functions. :)

---

BTW, doing `from turtle import *` is a bit messy. It's better to do something like:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.forward(50)
# etc
```